# Регулярное выражение (help)

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, поиск

Подскажите, пожалуйста, знающие люди, нужно в `html` странице произвести поиск на  `php`. Нужно найти:  `{something_text}`
Известно, что всегда будут фигурные скобки и что-то написанное латинскими символами.

Comment: очень размытый вопрос и совсем непонятно что Вы хотите реализовать. Опишите подробнее что именно вам нужно сделать.

Comment: @МихаилРебров спасибо за внимание. Уже помогли реализовать, то что задумывалось. По моему мнению, вопрос был прост и понятен, нужна была регулярка. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$text = 'asd {something_text}fsf ';
preg_match ("/\{[a-z_]+\}/",$text,$result);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: preg_math_all наверное надо. Если автору, конечно, это надо будет

Comment: Именно так) Спасибо)